# Unable to connect to Binance Websocket in c++

Tags: c++, websocket, bitcoin, binance, bybit

I am trying to connect to Binance Websocket in C++ using Boost library, but I keep getting errors like:

./main
Error: The WebSocket handshake was declined by the remote peer [boost.beast.websocket:20 at /opt/homebrew/opt/boost/include/boost/beast/websocket/impl/stream_impl.hpp:657:40 in function 'operator()']

Sometimes, I get timeout error, sometimes I get "connection closed before being established error" while at other times it successfully compiles and runs but no response is received.

```
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>


namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;            // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
int main()
{
    try
    {
        // Check command line arguments.
        // Check command line arguments.
        auto const host = "https://stream.binance.com";
        auto const port = "443";

        boost::property_tree::ptree json_data;
        //std::string param_body[] = {"btcusdt@trade"};
        //json_data.put("method", "SUBSCRIBE");
       // json_data.put("params", param_body);
        //json_data.put("id", 1);

        std::ostringstream oss;
        boost::property_tree::write_json(oss, json_data);
        std::string text = oss.str();

        // The io_context is required for all I/O
        net::io_context ioc;

        // These objects perform our I/O
        tcp::resolver resolver{ioc};
        websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws{ioc};

        // Look up the domain name
        auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port);

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        net::connect(ws.next_layer(), results.begin(), results.end());

        // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
        ws.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
            [](websocket::request_type& req)
            {
                req.set(http::field::user_agent,
                    std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                        " websocket-client-coro");
            }));

        // Perform the websocket handshake
        ws.handshake(host, "/ws/btcusdt@trade");

        // Send the message
        ws.write(net::buffer(std::string(text)));

        // This buffer will hold the incoming message
        beast::flat_buffer buffer;

        // Read a message into our buffer
        ws.read(buffer);

        // Close the WebSocket connection
        //ws.close(websocket::close_code::normal);

        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully

        // The make_printable() function helps print a ConstBufferSequence
        std::cout << beast::make_printable(buffer.data()) << std::endl;
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is one of the code snippets I am trying to use which is giving Websocket handshake declined error.

I created a server and client in C++ in my local system and was able to establish connection between them but when I am trying to connect to Binance or Bybit servers it either sends no response or sends these Websocket Handshake declined errors.

I have tried using other libraries instead of Boost as well, like Websocketpp, cURL etc but couldn't make it work. (I am using MacOS, if that helps in any way). I have tried using all combinations in the url and path etc, but they didn't help in any way.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.